# Matching Users while maximising value Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hungarian-algorithm

At the moment I have a database with `n` number of users. And all these users have a score associated with every other user, like a compatibility score. These scores are symetrical. So if user1 has a score of 10 with user2, then user2 will have a score of 10 with user1 etc.

I am looking for a way to match all users with each other, while maximising the total score for all users.

This is apparently known as the Hungarian Algorithm? Although looking for a maximum score instead of a minimum score.

Is there a clean way of doing this is Rails? I have looked everywhere and not being able to find anything.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is "everywhere"? Stack Overflow expects you'll show your attempts to solve the problem: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: This is often called the '[assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)' problem.  It is a type of linear programming problem for which a specialized algorithm can be used to obtain an optimum.  If the algorithm computes a maximum total score, simply negate the compatibility scores to use it to get a minimum total score.  Search `"assignment problem" algorithm` and you'll have no problem finding what you are looking for.